# Grails: Lookup Domain By Other Property than Identity

Tags: web-services, rest, grails, grails-orm

I'm using Grails 2.4.3 for a RESTful backend and we are generating external ID's that are returned in the JSON, but keeping the generated ID secret. On a GET request like:

```
/users/123456
```

I have the show method like so:

```
def show(User user) {
  respond user
}
```

The URL Mapping is simply:

```
"/users"(resources:"user")
```

Is there a way I can tell the User domain to lookup via `user.findByExternalId` rather than the id and keep the same code?

Comment: You could use: override `queryForResource` (and delete show method), just invoke `findByExternalId` and remove argument, create proxy command object which will behave as the fetched User class behind the scenes and modify argument. I think that real "get(id)" is invoked in `GrailsWebDataBinder#getPersistentInstance(Class<?> type, id)"` - but I couldn't override it in beans definition. I couldn't also intercept further execution by using `DataBindingListenerAdapter` which would return false on `beforeBinding` and invoke injected `simpleDataBinder.doBind` after correct fetch by external id.